# TypeError : this.refs.function is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

when i use the component directly which is DrawerLayoutAndroid from react-native i have a `ref="drawerAndroid"` then i call it in a function in the same component   with `this.refs.drawerAndroid.open()` it works but now i am using composition so i can't access to `this.refs.drawerAndroid` anymore.

So please why in the function open of the first component i can't access to `this.refs.drawerAndroid`?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { DrawerLayoutAndroid } from "react-native";

class CustomDrawer extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
  }

  renderDrawerAndroid() {
    return (
      <CustomDrawerLayoutAndroid
        ref="drawerAndroid"
        drawerWidth={250}
        drawerBackgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
        onDrawerOpen={this.props.onOpen}
        onDrawerClose={this.props.onClose}
        renderNavigationView={() => this.props.content}
      >
        {" "}
        {this.props.children}{" "}
      </CustomDrawerLayoutAndroid>
    );
  }

  open() {
    Platform.OS == "ios"
      ? this.refs.drawerIos.open()
      : this.refs.drawerAndroid.openDrawer();
  }
}

class CustomDrawerLayoutAndroid extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DrawerLayoutAndroid
        ref={this.props.ref}
        drawerWidth={this.props.drawerWidth}
        drawerBackgroundColor={this.props.drawerBackgroundColor}
        drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
        onDrawerOpen={this.props.onDrawerOpen}
        onDrawerClose={this.props.onDrawerClose}
        renderNavigationView={this.props.renderNavigationView}
      >
        {" "}
        {this.props.children}{" "}
      </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have copied and pasted your code, there is typo in your code. `reff`

Comment: yes i fixed it but it's not the cause of the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refs aren't working like that.

You should apply the reference of a component to a variable, not the opposite way.

In your case:

```
ref={this.props.ref}
```

should be something like

```
ref={r => 
  {  
    this.refs.android = r;
  }
}
```

Or you could use a function, is that case `ref={this.props.ref}` refers to

`refFunction = r => { this.refs.android = r; }`

```
class CustomDrawer extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
    this.refs = null;
  }

  setReferences = platform => r => {
     this.refs[platform] = r;
  }

  renderDrawerAndroid() {
    return (
      <CustomDrawerLayoutAndroid
        refFunction={this.setReferences("drawerAndroid")}
        drawerWidth={250}
        drawerBackgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
        onDrawerOpen={this.props.onOpen}
        onDrawerClose={this.props.onClose}
        renderNavigationView={() => this.props.content}
      >
        {" "}
        {this.props.children}{" "}
      </CustomDrawerLayoutAndroid>
    );
  }

  open() {
    Platform.OS == "ios"
      ? this.refs.drawerIos.open()
      : this.refs.drawerAndroid.openDrawer();
  }
}

class CustomDrawerLayoutAndroid extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DrawerLayoutAndroid
        ref={this.props.refFunction}
        drawerWidth={this.props.drawerWidth}
        drawerBackgroundColor={this.props.drawerBackgroundColor}
        drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
        onDrawerOpen={this.props.onDrawerOpen}
        onDrawerClose={this.props.onDrawerClose}
        renderNavigationView={this.props.renderNavigationView}
      >
        {" "}
        {this.props.children}{" "}
      </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
    );
  }
}
```

Also be careful when using props, as `ref` is a React-native props, you should not call any of the props you want to append to your child the same name. It's a source of conflict.

Comment: thank u hardworker for your effort it's so nice from you but still not working because this.refs is empty

Comment: what do you mean by it's empty ? if you put a console.log in setReferences function, do you see platform and reference ? is this.refs updated or still null ?

Comment: i see just plateform = "drawerAndroid" but this.refs  empty {}

Comment: thank u so much it works now i have just to put refFunction={(c) => this._refDrawer= c} then instead of this.refs.drawerAndroid i have to put this._refDrawer

Comment: glad i could help